# Geometry Question on Rationalizing Denominators

Tags: arithmetic

I am looking to check my answer to the problem : $\frac{5\sqrt{2} + 1}{2\sqrt{2} - 1}$. I think it is $3 + \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: That is not the simplification of the given expression.  Did you mean$$\frac{5\sqrt{2}+1}{2\sqrt{2}-1}$$

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha says “False”](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5*sqrt%282%29+%2B+1%2F%282*sqrt%282%29%29+-+1+%3D+3+%2B+sqrt%282%29).

Comment: Yes, tht is what I meant.

Comment: Then your simplification is correct...

Answer (score 1):

Rationalize the denominator. Multiply it by it conjugate.

$$\frac{5\sqrt{2} + 1}{2\sqrt{2} - 1} = \frac{5\sqrt{2} + 1}{2\sqrt{2} - 1} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt{2} + 1}{2\sqrt{2} + 1} = \frac{(5\sqrt{2} + 1)(2\sqrt{2} + 1)}{(2\sqrt{2})^2 - 1^2} = \frac{21 + 7\sqrt{2}}{7} = 3 + \sqrt{2}$$

So yes, your answer is right.